# Python column addition of numpy arrays with shift

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

How can i accomplish column addition with shift using python numpy arrays ?

I have two dimensional array and need it's extended copy.

```
a = array([[0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
       [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]])
```

i want something like (following is in pseudo code, it doesn't work; there is no `a.columns` in `numpy` as far as i know):

```
shift = 3
mult_factor = 0.7
for column in a.columns - shift :
    out[column] = a[column] + 0.7 * a[column + shift]
```

I also know, that i can do the something similar to what i need using indexes. But i seems that is really overkill enumerating three values and using only one (j) :

```
for (i,j),value in np.ndenumerate(a):
    print i,j
```

I founded, that i could iterate over columns, but not their indexes:

```
for column in a.T:
    print column
```

Than i though that i can simply do this with something that is similar to xrange, but applying to multidimensional array:

```
In [225]: for column in np.ndindex(a.shape[1]):
            print column
   .....:     
(0,)
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(4,)
```

So now i only know how to do this with simple xrange and i am not sure, that is the best solution.

```
out = np.zeros(a.shape)
shift = 2
mult_factor = 0.7
for i in xrange(a.shape[1]-shift):
    print a[:, i]
    out[:, i] =  a[:, i] + mult_factor * a[:, i+shift]
```

However it will be not so fast in Python as it maybe can be. 
Can you give me an advice how it will be in performance and maybe there is more faster way to accomplish column addition of numpy arrays with shift ?

Comment: What version of numpy is this? (The `a.columns` doesn't work for me). Also, could you explain what the output of the shift should be?

Comment: `a.columns` will not work  it is pseudo code, representing what i really need. 
shift is an offset used to add columns, nothing more
so in first output column should be first input column `plus` first+shift column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out = a[:, :-shift] + mult_factor * a[:, shift:]
```

I think this is what you're looking for. It's a vectorized form of your loop, operating on large slices of `a` instead of column by column.

Comment: so in general in numpy vector arithmetic vectors should be equal length. I tried something similar, but no so elegent as this.
Can you explain, please, how `numpy` performs this addition  ?

Comment: @PavelShvechikov: There are a lot of different possible answers to that question, depending on which aspect you actually need answered. You could take a look at the [broadcasting tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which has a good chance of answering questions about how NumPy handles arithmetic operations on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I completely understand what the computed quantity should be, but here are two things that seem germane to what you are asking:

1. If you have a 2D array, called `a` that you wish to convert to a list of 1D arrays which are the columns of `a` you can do this

   cols = [c for c in a.T]
2. It looks like what you want can be accomplished with matrix multiplication if I am not mistaken. You could make a banded matrix in numpy using `numpy.diag` or, since you would have the same values along each band 1, mult_factor, or 0, you could use `scipy.linalg.toeplitz`

   m,n = a.shape
   band = np.eye(1,n)
   band[0,shift] = mult_factor
   T = scipy.linalg.toeplitz(np.eye(1,m),band)
   out = np.inner(a,T)

For large matrices, it might make sense to use a sparse matrix for `T` if you only want to add two or a few columns of `a`.